# Making objects from instances

Tags: animation, node-editor, instances

I'm trying to create a random array from a group of objects and have used animation nodes as show in the screenshot.  It works perfectly well and allows adjustment of the 'assortment' using the random seed.
[image]
My problem is that i would like now to act on the array items to make individuals rotate at random - in all likelihood, the final objects will all be spheres with a variety of images textured onto them - but i can't separate the array from the original group, they remain resolutely as instances.  I've tried 'separating loose parts', Ctrl+Alt+A and other techniques gleaned from then net but none of them work.

Am i missing a point - can they not be separated into individual objects?

Thoughts and advice much appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i44t757z4rlui4i/AN%20array%20-%20v1.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

When you get the array you want with AN, delete the AN nodetree and the objects will remain (you may have to be in +1 frame).

This will give control of the objects back to you. However each object copied from the group instance will share the Vertex information. Go to the Object Data view and create Single user for each object.
[image]

You can now bring in these objects into AN to manipulate again as you wish.

Comment: Thank you Bfoot, I understand the approach but my final array could have around 500 objects which would be quite a task.  You got me thinking though and I seemed to have solved it by selecting the array and Shift+D gives me an identical array of discrete objects which i can then manipulate.  Has the advantage of not deleting the node tree so i can go back and amend the array later if i need to.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Good ideas. Also like your non-destructive idea of keeping the node-tree.